# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header In jQuery Ajax Login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I have a Login Page called `login.php` which is in the main first root level and `users.php` which is in `assets/app/users.php`. I am using jQuery ajax to do the login process. In the JS part of `login.php` I have:

```
    if(loginProceed){
        var data = {email: loginEmail, pass:  loginPass};
        var loginreq = $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url : "assets/app/users.php",
                                cache: false,
                                data: data
                          });

    loginreq.done(function(html) {
   if(html=='true'){
       window.location.replace('app.php'); }
   else  {
    $("#loginRequest").before('<div class="alert alert-danger err" role="alert">Email or Password Is Not Correct</div>');
    }
    });    
}
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

and in `users.php` I have

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start(); 
include 'config.php';
           $email = $_POST['email'];
           $pass  = $_POST['pass'];
           $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);                
           $sql = "SELECT id, email, fname, lname, type FROM users WHERE `email`=? AND `pass`=?";              
           $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
           $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email,$pass);
           $stmt->execute();
           $stmt->bind_result($theId,$theEmail,$theFName,$theLname,$theType);
           if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo 'true';
                $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'] = true;
                $_SESSION['fname'] = $theFName;
           } else {
                echo 'false';
            }
```

Now this is doing the Login process for me in all browsers but for some other users it ONLY works on Chrome! or even on none of them and we are getting theses errors in console:

> login.js:74 Object login.php:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://domain.ca/login.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.ca' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

or on FireFox

> Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a
>   security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn
>   More]  "SensorNotRequired:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages"
>   util.js:30:57

and on EI

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x4c7, The operation was
>   canceled by the user.

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try to allow single domain

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domain.ca');
```

or try modify .htaccess with `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
[enter link description here](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

Look like your script is loaded from domain.ca ( without www ) but you or other user making request to php from www.domain.ca

Comment: Thanks Stefan , you are right! even me not able to login when adding the `www` at the begining of the domain! but even the `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domain.ca');` not solving the problem?!